# NGXS State Changed Event

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I have an NGXS store that contains (lets say) an object. obj = { name: 'so-and-so', age: 42, nationality: 'country-name', address: { ... } }. When I update any of the properties (even nested propeties, eg. 'address'), it should be displayed in the UI. But properties are updated from multiple sources. I want to keep the entire object in one store as a single source of truth.

Can NGXS emit 'state-changed' whenever a property is changed? This can be subscribed using observables and respective part of the UI can me updated with the latest value.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a select function. https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select